# how to draw a line graph in ios? Any control which will help me show graph data in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, linegraph, ios-charts

I want to create a customized graph.

Which will show on Y axis number of mathces e.g. 4

Y axis legends will be the starting date and ending date.

And on X axis a line graph will plot the points on the status of the each match E.g.

Win,
Draw,
Loss.

How to do this in Objective C!??

Comment: Have you done any web searches for "iOS graph library"? You could also look on https://maniacdev.com

Comment: Yes I have searched for open source controls as well
But they are usually used only to show stock information and are not customizable.

Comment: See my answer. If you look at the source code libraries listed, you may be able to find some code you can modify to suit your needs.

Comment: @stevekohls Okay. Thank you for the support. And apologies for an unclear question. Next time i will try to be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

To create line graph just we need one UIBezier path and one  CAShapeLayer, pass the co ordinate points based on the data you have  to the UiBezierpath that will create the line graph then add that path to layer.

Here is the code to create line graph,

```
//Bezier path for ploting graph
_graphPath = [[UIBezierPath alloc]init];
[_graphPath setLineWidth:10];

//CAShapeLayer for graph allocation
_graphLayout = [CAShapeLayer layer];
_graphLayout.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width*0, 0, self.frame.size.width*0.8, (self.frame.size.height*0.9));
_graphLayout.fillColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:255 alpha:0.1] CGColor];
_graphLayout.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
_graphLayout.lineWidth = 2;
_graphLayout.path = [_graphPath CGPath];
_graphLayout.lineCap = @"round";
_graphLayout.lineJoin = @"round";
[self.layer addSublayer:_graphLayout];
```

The code to add line to point and move to point

```
[_graphPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(coord.x, coord.y)];
[_graphPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(coord.x, coord.y)];
_graphLayout.path = [_graphPath CGPath];
```

Answer (score 2):

I've made a method for returning a view with data points plotted:

```
-(UIView *)createGraphWithFrameSize:(CGSize)frameSize
                     lineColor:(UIColor *)lineColor
                      xAxisMin:(float)xAxisMin
                      xAxisMax:(float)xAxisMax
                      yAxisMin:(float)yAxisMin
                      yAxisMax:(float)yAxisMax
                    dataPoints:(NSArray <NSValue *> *)dataPoints {

    UIView *graph = [UIView new];

    graph.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    graph.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, frameSize.width, frameSize.height);

    //

    CAShapeLayer *line = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    UIBezierPath *linePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    int i = 0;

    while (i < dataPoints.count) {

        CGPoint point = [dataPoints[i] CGPointValue];

        float xRatio = 1.0-((xAxisMax-point.x)/(xAxisMax-xAxisMin));
        float yRatio = 1.0-((yAxisMax-point.y)/(yAxisMax-yAxisMin));

        float x = xRatio*frameSize.width;
        float y = (1.0-yRatio)*frameSize.height;

        if (i == 0) {
            [linePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(x, y)];
        } else {
            [linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x, y)];
        }

        i++;

    }

    line.lineWidth = 2.0;
    line.path = linePath.CGPath;
    line.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    line.strokeColor = [lineColor CGColor];
    [graph.layer addSublayer:line];

    //

    graph.clipsToBounds = YES;

    return graph;

}
```

Example usage:

```
#define xy(__x,__y) [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(__x,__y)]

    UIView *plotView = [self createGraphWithFrameSize:CGSizeMake(300, 300)
                                            lineColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.8]
                                             xAxisMin:-5
                                             xAxisMax:5
                                             yAxisMin:-5
                                             yAxisMax:5
                                           dataPoints:@[xy(-5,-4),
                                                        xy(0,3),
                                                        xy(5,-4)]];

    plotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:0.5];
    [self.view addSubview:plotView];
```

Comment: can you explain how to implement it in project.

Comment: @muthukumaresh I had already included an example usage in the second section. Copy paste the first section into the body of your view controller .m file, then copy paste the second section into a method of said .m, for example viewDidLoad