# Generate small thumbnail image of MKPolyline without a MKMapView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, mkmapview, mkoverlay

Our app contains several MKPolyline boundaries that all create a closed in polygon. These are primarily to display as an MKOverlay on a MKMapView but I'm looking for a solution to display these polygons as small thumbnails to be visible not on the MKMapView but instead as a standard UIImage or UIImageView.

Just to be clear, I'm wanting these small thumbnails would just be displayed as small shapes that have a stroke color and a fill color but without any map background.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: can you share screenshot of your design that will help me to answer your question in better way

Comment: @bmindhacker Sure, here is a mockup with the boundary thumbnails circled in red: http://cl.ly/dy2A.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
+ (UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name withColor:(UIColor *)color{
    // load the image
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:name];

    // begin a new image context, to draw our colored image onto
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.size);

    // get a reference to that context we created
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // set the fill color
    [color setFill];

    // translate/flip the graphics context (for transforming from CG* coords to UI* coords
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, img.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    // set the blend mode to color burn, and the original image
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeColorBurn);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, img.CGImage);

    // set a mask that matches the shape of the image, then draw (color burn) a colored rectangle
    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, img.CGImage);
    CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
    CGContextDrawPath(context,kCGPathFill);

    // generate a new UIImage from the graphics context we drew onto
    UIImage *coloredImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //return the color-burned image
    return coloredImg;
}
```

Please check this [original](https://coffeeshopped.com/2010/09/iphone-how-to-dynamically-color-a-uiimage) post for detail description.

Comment: This shoes how to dynamically change the color of a UIImage but does not explain how to generate the UIImage thumbnail from a MKPolyline. Could you help with this?

Comment: As i saw your image and according to this you just need to pas image to the detail dont need  MKPolyline

Comment: The image is just a mockup. I'm starting with MKPolylines and those UIImage thumbnails first need to be generated from the map points without using a MKMapView.

Comment: Any more ideas on this?

Comment: well i am confused about your problem and not getting it

Comment: I'm not sure how else to describe it. I want to draw the shape made by a MKPolyline as a thumbnail image without having a map background.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do exactly the same in my own app. Here is my solution : I generate a `UIView` which represents path's shape. In your case the path is a `MKPolyline`.

Here is my code :

```
+ (UIView *)createShapeForGPX:(GPX *)gpx
                withFrameSize:(CGSize)frameSize
                    lineColor:(UIColor *)lineColor {

    // Array of coordinates (Adapt this code with your coordinates)
    // Note : in my case I have a double loops because points are in paths 
    // and I can have many paths for one route. So I concact all points 
    // into one array to simplify the code for your case. If you also have
    // many paths, you have to change a little bit next code.
    NSMutableArray<NSValue *> *dataPoints = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSArray *path in gpx.paths) {
        for (NSDictionary *point in path) {
            double latitude = [point[@"latitude"] doubleValue];
            double longitude = [point[@"longitude"] doubleValue];
            [dataPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(longitude, latitude)]];
        }
    }

    // Graph bounds (You need to calculate topRightCoordinate and bottomleftCoordinate. You can do it in previous for loop)
    double lngBorder = gpx.topRightCoordinate.longitude - gpx.bottomLeftCoordinate.longitude;
    double latBorder = gpx.topRightCoordinate.latitude - gpx.bottomLeftCoordinate.latitude;

    double middleLng = gpx.bottomLeftCoordinate.longitude + (lngBorder / 2.f);
    double middleLat = gpx.bottomLeftCoordinate.latitude + (latBorder / 2.f);

    double boundLength = MAX(lngBorder, latBorder);

    // *** Drawing ***
    CGFloat margin = 4.f;
    UIView *graph = [UIView new];
    graph.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, frameSize.width - margin, frameSize.height - margin);

    CAShapeLayer *line = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    UIBezierPath *linePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    float xAxisMin = middleLng - (boundLength / 2.f);
    float xAxisMax = middleLng + (boundLength / 2.f);
    float yAxisMin = middleLat - (boundLength / 2.f);
    float yAxisMax = middleLat + (boundLength / 2.f);

    int i = 0;
    while (i < dataPoints.count) {

        CGPoint point = [dataPoints[i] CGPointValue];

        float xRatio = 1.0-((xAxisMax-point.x)/(xAxisMax-xAxisMin));
        float yRatio = 1.0-((yAxisMax-point.y)/(yAxisMax-yAxisMin));

        float x = xRatio*(frameSize.width - margin / 2);
        float y = (1.0-yRatio)*(frameSize.height - margin);

        if (i == 0) {
            [linePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(x, y)];
        } else {
            [linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x, y)];
        }
        i++;
    }

    // Line
    line.lineWidth = 0.8;
    line.path = linePath.CGPath;
    line.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    line.strokeColor = [lineColor CGColor];
    [graph.layer addSublayer:line];

    graph.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // Final view (add margins)
    UIView *finalView = [UIView new];
    finalView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    finalView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, frameSize.width, frameSize.height);
    graph.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(finalView.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(finalView.bounds));
    [finalView addSubview:graph];

    return finalView;
}
```

In my case `GPX` class contains few values :
- `NSArray<NSArray<NSDictionary *> *> *paths;` : contains all points of all paths. In your case I think it is your `MKPolyline`.
- `topRightCoordinate` and `bottomLeftCoordinate` : Two `CLLocationCoordinate2D` that represent top right and bottom left virtual coordinates of my path (you have to calcul them also).

You call this method like that : 
`UIView *shape = [YOURCLASS createShapeForGPX:gpx withFrameSize:CGSizeMake(32, 32) lineColor:[UIColor blackColor]];`

This solution is based on this question [how to draw a line graph in ios? Any control which will help me show graph data in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31963336/how-to-draw-a-line-graph-in-ios-any-control-which-will-help-me-show-graph-data/31989504) which gives a solution to draw a graph from points.

Maybe all this code is not usefull for you (like margins) but it should help you to find your own solution.

Here is how it displays in my app (in a `UITableView`) :

[image]